# How to cast an object to a given generic type so I can pass this object to method

Tags: java, generics, lambda, interface, casting

I have a class "Event" with one generic argument - T.
It's the type of Event and is always an interface.
Events listener must implement event types that it wants to "listen".

For example:

```
public class GuiHandler implements Startup, GuiChanged
```

But there is only one way to register this events listener. Just take all the events it implements and invoke "register" method with events listener instance or method reference.

I'm trying to make an "EventManager" class that could detect if given object's class implements "event.getType() (which returns T of event)" and if it does, cast object to this event type and register in event.

```
public static void register(Object listener) {
    for (Event<?> event : Event.EVENTS)
        if (listener.getClass().isInstance(event.getType()))
            event.register(event.getType().cast(listener));
}
```

But for some reason it says

> The method register(capture#3-of ?) in the type
>   Event is not applicable for the arguments
>   (capture#4-of ?)

Events are made like this:

```
new Event<>(GuiChanged.class, (listeners) -> 
    (/*some event specific arguments*/) -> {
        for (GuiChanged event : listeners) {
            event.onGuiSchnged(/*some event specific arguments*/);
        }
    });
```

And the constructor is:

```
public Event(Class<T> type, Function<T[], T> functionToUse) {
        this.type = type;
        this.functionToUse = functionToUse;
        EVENTS = Arrays.copyOf(EVENTS, EVENTS.length + 1);
        EVENTS[EVENTS.length - 1] = this;
    }
```

Please help. I believe it's possible.

Comment: Can you show the method declaration of `Event#register`?

Comment: It's `public void register(T listener)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution is easy. All I had to do is remove `<?>` from "EVENTS" array and just use "isAssignableFrom" to check if listener implements given event type. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should use a different design. Currently, your `Event` class is responsible to hold all its listeners, but in theory the event should only hold related event data.

```
public class Event<T> {
    private Class<T> eventClass;
    private T data;

    // rest ommitted for brevity
}
```

An `EventListener` holds the related type of events that it should process and the processing method itself.

```
public interface EventListener<T> {
    Class<T> getType();
    void notify(T event);
}
```

Your `EventManager` is then responsible to hold the listeners and fire related events. I have used a `Map` here to quickly identity listeners that should be notified about a specific event.

```
public class EventManager {

    private Map<Class<?>, EventListener<?>> listeners = new HashMap<>();

    public registerListener(EventListener<?> listener) {
        // ...
    }

    public void fire(Event<?> event) {
        EventListener<?> listener = listeners.get(event.getEventClass());
        if(listener != null) {
            listener.notify(event);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you can only hold one `EventListener` per type in the above example (for simplicity). Use a `List<EventListener<?>>` instead, if you want to support multiple listeners per class. Also, abobe classes are only prototyped, there are additional casts required, but those are type safe, since the generic type of `Event<T>` always refers to the same class as `getEventClass()`.

Example use case:

- For your event: `new Event(data, GuiChangedData.class);`
- Related listener:

  ```
  public class GuiChangedListener implements EventListener<GuiChangedData> {
      // ...
  }
  ```

If you need additional information, feel free to ask.

Comment: That's not really what I want. I wanna make it so event can execute listener directly, without any "eventdata" and "fire" methods. Currently it can be run like this: `GuiChanged.EVENT.getInvoker().onGuiChanged(/*some event data*/);` and I wanna keep this one cuz IMHO it's faster and lighter. And if only 1 listener is registered, it'll be executed directly, without `functionToUse` execution.